# How do I calculate time lag between true value and predicted value

Tags: time-series, forecasting, lags

I have a prediction model to predicted time-series data.  the result is as below:
[image]

you can see that the predicted value have lag compared to label. Is is possible to calculate a value to tell me how many step the predicted value is lagged? so I don't have to check plot manually, because there are too many of them.

Comment: Are you using temporal difference learning?

Comment: No, I just use LSTM  to predict  value of next time step

Comment: For many forecasting methods (ARIMA and beyond), the lag would equal the forecast horizon, so it is enough to know the latter. So if you are forecasting $h$ periods into the future, the lag will be $h$. This would not apply to forecasts from some other methods such as $k$ nearest neighbours, though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'd do:

1. Start with a dataframe that contains two columns: `label` and `prediction`.
2. Create a third column named `lagged_1_pred`.
3. Populated the `lagged_1_pred` column by applying the lag function on `prediction`. Use a lag period of 1 (`k`=1). See this link for a reference to the `lag` function in R: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.0/topics/lag 
   Note that you can do this in Excel too by simply taking the value from the previous row.
4. Take the difference of `label` and `lagged_1_pred`. Let's call it `diff_1`.
5. Calculate the sum of `diff_1` column. And then discard `lagged_1_pred` and `diff_1` columns.
6. Repeat steps 2 to 5 for a new column named `lagged_2_pred`. Use `k`=2.
7. Repeat steps 2 to 5 for a new column named `lagged_3_pred`. Use `k`=3.
8. Continue for `k`=4, 5..., K. Where K is some reasonably high value, e.g., 250  (based on a visual inspection of the chart).
9. At the end, you will have sum(`diff_1`), sum(`diff_2`),...., sum(`diff_K`).
10. Find the minimum absolute value across all of these sums.
11. That's your answer! (If you find our that sum(`diff_95`) is the absolute minimum value across all sums, then your answer is 95).

The basic idea is to find which lag value (`k`) gives you the minimum total (absolute) difference between the prediction and label.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you should consider just a lag, like a simple constant deviation between real values and predicted values of the model **AFTER** a fit.

Fitting data means that you obtain the better fit searching for something.

For exemple, the OLS (ordinary least squares) model finds the better fit searching for the coefficients that minimizes the sum of the squared residuals (including the intercept).

Your model searches for something too, and push or pull data within a period after a fit does not mean that you will predict future values with precision. If you manually adjusts the intercept, the other coefficients will lose what the modeling wanted to find.

So you need to find a better model!

You could search for correlation (residuals and dependent variables). And verify econometric assumptions (prediction depends on that, while fitting a model is just math with no intrinsic meaning) (1).

I think this offers a direction:

> **Applying 2SLS in a time series context**
>
> When there are concerns of
>   included endogenous variables in a model t to time series data, we
>   have a natural source of instruments in terms of predetermined
>   variables. For instance, if y2t is an explanatory variable, its own
>   lagged values, y2t.1 or y2t.2, might be used as instruments: they are
>   likely to be correlated with y2t, and they will not be correlated with
>   the error term at time t; since they were generated at an earlier
>   point in time. The one caveat that must be raised in this context
>   relates to autocorrelated errors: if the errors are themselves
>   autocorrelated, then the presumed exogeneity of predetermined
>   variables will be in doubt. Tests for autocorrelated errors should be
>   conducted; in the presence of autocorrelation, more distant lags
>   might be used to mitigate this concern.

[Wooldridge, Introductory Econometrics, 4th
ed., Chapter 15: Instrumental variables and two
stage least squares] - [You can find it here](http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-c/f2010/228/EC228.f2010.nn15.pdf).

(1) For OLS: [Gauss-Markov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem)